# Obtener Nombre y otros datos del usuario actual de wordpres y Buscar sus referidos

Tags: php, wordpress

En mi proyecto en una de las paginas del backoffice que he creado para el usuario es la de ver mis referidos, estoy utilizando wordpress, y esta página de referido lo haré mediante php ya que he de realizar consultas en las BBDD.

Se que con esta funcion recupero las variables que quiera del usuario logeado:

```
if (is_user_logged_in()){

            $cu = wp_get_current_user();


            echo 'Nombre de usuario: ' . $cu->user_login     . '<br />';


    }
```

De hecho esto lo he puesto en mi php y me da un error no se si esta función lo he de poner en el functions y luego pasarlo a otro php o no?

La consulta y demas se como hacerla me falta obtener el usuario logeado y con eso ya haría la consulta.

Comment: ¿Que error te da?

Answer (score 0):

Ya esta solucionado, tenia que añadir este código en la pagina para poder utilizarla y visualizarla.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: visualizador de niveles
*/
?>
<?php

get_header();

$is_page_builder_used = et_pb_is_pagebuilder_used( get_the_ID() );

?>
```